# Is there a C# method overload parameter ordering convention?

Tags: c#, coding-style, conventions, overloading

Is there any sort of convention in C# (or any object oriented language that supports method overloading) for the following situation?

Lets say I have a method foo:

```
public void Foo(int a){//does stuff}
```

But actually I have 3 methods foo:

```
public void Foo(int a){}
public void Foo(int a, double b){}
public void Foo(float c, int a, double b){}
```

Is there a convention that states whether or not the order of parameters matters in an overloaded method? Notice how the 3rd method doesn't an obvious logical progression (a,b,c).

Comment: If `a` is always required, and `b` is required if `c` is provided, I would do something like this:  `public void Foo(int a, double? b = null, float? c = null)` - assuming your logic is the same.

Comment: @zimdanen, there is no reason to make params nullable

Comment: @Jupiter: The idea is to use that as an alternative to overloads. It works well when there are multiple parameters all of which are independent - you avoid doubling the number of overloads every time you add another. (Admittedly once you've got to about 5 parameters you should be looking really carefully at whether this is an appropriate design anyway...)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes there is. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229029(v=vs.110).aspx

> Do be consistent in the ordering of parameters in overloaded members. Parameters with the same name should appear in the same position in all overloads.

Comment: And further, you should only overload methods for the purposes of providing default values to a common method. Otherwise, the methods are not strongly related enough to have the same name, and should be given different names.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not required to maintain a specific order, it is generally a good idea to do so, for the sake of readability. The order of the parameters does matter for the method signature however. For example,

```
public void DoStuff(int a, bool b, string c)
{

}

public void DoStuff(bool b, string c, int a)
{

}
```

is valid and compiles just fine, even though the number of parameters, and even their names are the same.

Update: I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. It could lead to confusion. I was just stating that it is technically valid.

Comment: While this is valid, it would be totally confusing to those using the method.

Comment: Exactly, that is why I said it is a good idea to maintain order for readability. I personally would not do it in this manner. I was just stating for the record that the order of parameters does factor in to the method's signature. If it didn't, the compiler would have a harder time differentiating between the overloads.